# Programatically clicking on an anchor in android WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to load a website in an android  webview and programtically click on an anchor in its code.

the anchor is in a div feild :

```
<div id="_item_row_677305">

    <span id="parent-row-song677305" class="parentnode sourcelist_1" style="display:none;"> … </span>
    <ul id="trackrow677305" class="playlist clearfix ">
        <li class="playcol" data-value="677305">
            <div>
                <a class="songlist play_pause playicon677305 " title="Play" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="song677305" data-type="playSong"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="songcol"> … </li>
        <li class="artistcol"> … </li>
        <li class="popularitycol popular"> … </li>
        <li class="eventcol"> … </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

I cant figure out how to do this. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you know which function this anchor will call. So you can simply use a WeViewClient to do this stuff.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:here is the function's name you need to invoke");
    }
}
```

And after this, just set your webview's webclient.